# Whenever I start a project, an error occurs :main namespace specified in project.clj

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

Whichever github project I run I get the same error.

Now I have started a simple example from the book clojure for brave and true and the same program appears.

```
(ns clojure-noob.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "I'm a little teapot!"))
```

error is

```bash
>   PS C:\Users\danny\New folder\cftbat-code> lein run
No :main namespace specified in project.clj.
```

what can i do and what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is surprising!  Apparently typing `lein new myproj` does not include a necessary line in the result.  In particular, your `project.clj` file needs a line like this:

```
  :main myproj.core
```

Change it to look like the following:

```
(defproject myproj "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.3"]]
  :repl-options {:init-ns myproj.core}
  :main myproj.core
  )
```

and

```
(ns myproj.core)

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!" args))
```

with result

```bash
> lein clean; lein run abc
Hello, World! (abc)
```

---

### Another option

Having said that, I never use `lein new xxx` anymore. Instead, I just clone [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template), then modify it.

Just check out the README and follow along!

---

### Extra details

You can also specify the "main function" to run on the command line. Since the name of the default "main function" is `-main`, you can tell `lein run` the namespace containing the `-main` function by typing:

```bash
> lein clean ; lein run :main myproj.core
Hello, World! nil
```

If your "main function" is not `-main`, then type something like

```bash
> lein clean ; lein run :main myproj.core/foo
```

When you have compilation failues (especially if macros are involved), it is always safest to delete all previous `*.class` files via `lein clean`. If you don't, maybe one in a hundred times you will get very strange failures that cannot be explained.

I find it safest to define and always use an alias:

```bash
alias lcr="lein do clean, run"
alias lct="lein do clean, test"
```

The version with `do` is about 1 second faster than `lein clean; lein run`, but don't forget the comma!

---

### How to avoid

OK, I just remembered a way to avoid the problem.  Just type:

```bash
lein new app myapp
```

This will include the line

```bash
  :main ^:skip-aot myapp.core
```

which was missing when you just type `lein new myproj` (i.e. with out the `app` part).

Comment: any idea what can I do or where to post?

Comment: Is it surprising? A lot of Clojure projects are libraries, not applications, and so having no `:main` seems reasonable. (By the way, `lein clean` is necessary 0% of the time unless you have really badly messed up a project)